# Not able to log in to the alfresco application

Tags: centos, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am new to alfresco/centos.

The Problem is 
`http://localhost:7070/alfresco`  --- getting page error
`http://localhost:7070/share`  --- log in page is opening but cannot able to log in to the application.
username/password using is admin/admin.

As my observation i got to know that, in etc/hosts(host file are missing) file i need to add alfresco IP address and server name. I tried different alfresco IP address by searching in net. But it is not working, And i added some supporting file to that. But no use.

Any solution!!

Catalina.out file:

WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'debug' to '0' did not find a matching property.
Jul 03, 2014 3:41:37 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [1,208] milliseconds.
2014-07-03 15:41:44,933
WARN  [solr.core.SolrCore] [localhost-startStop-1] [archive] Solr index directory '/opt/alfresco/alf_data/solr/archive/SpacesStore/index' doesn't exist. Creating new index$
 2014-07-03 15:41:45,537
WARN  [handler.component.SpellCheckComponent] [localhost-startStop-1] No queryConverter defined, using default converter
 2014-07-03 15:41:48,273
WARN  [solr.core.SolrCore] [localhost-startStop-1] [alfresco] Solr index directory '/opt/alfresco/alf_data/solr/workspace/SpacesStore/index' doesn't exist. Creating new i$
 2014-07-03 15:41:48,314  WARN  [handler.component.SpellCheckComponent] [localhost-startStop-1] No queryConverter defined, using default converter

These are the warnings coming from catalina.out

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If `/alfresco/` isn't there then you won't be able to log in. Any handy hints about why Alfresco didn't start in the tomcat logs?

Comment: Did you check `alfresco.log` for exceptions?

Comment: Yes i checked alfresco.log, there i am getting "Context initialization failure"

Comment: There's normally something before that explaining why it couldn't initialize it. One of your logs should have an `ERROR` which gives the details

Comment: 2014-07-05 18:36:30,021  ERROR [solr.tracker.CoreTracker] [SolrTrackerScheduler_Worker-3] Tracking failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 06050119 GetModelsDiff return status is 404. this is the error am getting. If i delete solr file. i am getting 404 error message.

Comment: There should be something before that - that's just solr saying it can't talk to the repository as the repo didn't start

Comment: Now i got another error.  ERROR [util.exec.RuntimeExecBootstrapBean] [localhost-startStop-1] Bootstrap command failed: 
Execution result: 
   os:         Linux
   command:    /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin -accept=socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager -env:UserInstallation=file:///opt/alfresco/alf_data/oouser -headless -nocrashreport -nofirststartwizard -nologo -norestore
   succeeded:  false
   exit code:  2
   out:        
   err:        Cannot run program "/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin": error=2, No such file or director.

Comment: Problem sloved, i edited in alfresco-global.properties file.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely hitting the sharepoint service which is not meant  to be used with a browser. Try `http://localhost:8080/share/` or `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, during installation i gave port as 7070